# AttributeError: module 'google.api_core' has no attribute 'gapic_v1' (Dataflow)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, dataflow

I have been experimenting an error while trying to add google-cloud-storage to my dataflow pipeline.
The pipeline was working just fine before importing storage along with some other google packages. In local works fine, no errors, good processing, but when I deploy it always gets a similar error

`line 233, in SecretManagerServiceClient retry=google.api_core.gapic_v1.method.DEFAULT, AttributeError: module 'google.api_core' has no attribute 'gapic_v1'`

I have tried different versions of each package but I haven't achieve any success yet.

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="pipeline",
    version="1.0",
    # This works similar to a requirements.txt file
    # https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/
    install_requires=[
        "apache-beam==2.20.0",
        "python-magic==0.4.15",
        "PyMuPDF==1.16.18",
        "sentry-sdk==0.15.1",
        "google-api-python-client==2.1.0",
        "google-apitools==0.5.30",
        "google-api-core==1.23.0",
        "google-auth==1.23.0",
        "google-cloud-core==1.4.4",
        "google-cloud-secret-manager==1.0.0",
        "google-cloud-tasks==1.5.0",
        "google-cloud-pubsub==1.4.2",
        "google-cloud-storage==1.26.0",
        "urllib3==1.25.11",
        "pusher==3.0.0",
    ],
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    data_files=[(".", ["cacert.pem"])],
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Github issue that seems to address this very same error, please check [1]. The workaround provided on the issue is to downgrade to previous versions, which may imply other incompatibility issues on the other hand.

Could you test the workaround and see if it fixes the issue?

[1] -
https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues/115